# Why the elapsedTime property of animation event is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, css-animations

I'm trying to access the `elapsedTime` property of animation events as shown in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations).

When i inspect the object i can see the property with the corresponding value, However when i log it in console i'm getting undefined. Following is the sample code:

HTML

```
<div id='box'></div>
```

CSS

```
#box {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  animation: move 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% { left: 0; }
  50% { left:90%; }
  100% { left: 0;}
}
```

JS

```
$("#box").on("animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration", function (e) {
  console.log(e.elapsedTime); // this logs undefined
});
```

I've setup a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bqq4s/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
console.log(e.originalEvent.elapsedTime);
```

In the javaScript event, the variable is elapsedtime, so you can access it as you did

javascriptevent.elapsedTime

However, you are setting the event function in jQuery. the jQuery event has a lot of the javascript variables mirrored, but not all.

To access the javascript variables not mirrored in the jQuery event, you have the *originalEvent* object, that is the original javascript event, inside the jQuery event.

So, the syntax is

jQueryEvent.originalEvent.elapsedTime

Use the same syntax to access all the variables not mirrored in the jQuery event

Comment: But in the example from the docs it's being accessed simply like `e.elapsedTime` O.o

Comment: If you are adding an event listener in javascript element.addEventListener (...), you will receive a javascript event. And then, the syntax will be the one that you say. But, if you are using jQuery, you will receive a jQuery event. And then , you will need the syntax that I told you.

Comment: Could you please update the answer mentioning this is the jquery syntax as well as the js syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the line of code below in `function onAnimationProgress(event)`

`if (ev.elapsedTime === undefined) ev.elapsedTime = maxDuration;`